# Regex to find filepaths - with some subtilities?

Tags: regex

I need to parse some files and find detect all filepaths in them.

At the moment, I use this expression, which works 99% of the time:

```regex
(".*\/.*?\.[\w:\.]+)
```

But, on something like this:

```
someFunction("Default","Asset/NiceAssetTab/Lighting/MuchLighting.act")
```

It outputs
`"Default","Asset/NiceAssetTab/Lighting/MuchLighting.act`

How could I improve my regex without changing the already present functionalities?

Alternatively, if it's easier, here is some details on the paths I'm trying to detect:

- They start after a "
- A single file can have multiple extensions in its name : "file.png.tga.txt.ooo"
- Paths can have extensions in their folder name : "niceFolder.png/niceFile.lua" (...)
- They have at least one "." (for the extension)

Thanks :)

Comment: Your "details" section might need some work: there is nothing "wtf" about multiple extensions. The llast one is the extension, everything else is filename. Like `models.stored.test.js` next to `models.memonly.test.js` in a dir called `models`. The real question is "what _defines_ a path in your data". Because right now it looks like it's the fairly trivial [`"[^"\/]+(\/[^"\/]+)+"`](https://regex101.com/r/Ohp7ET/1), i.e. "start term, followed by one or more /terms". (On that note: use https://regex101.com, it is a crucial when write and testing regex =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
It works in this case, but fails in other, for example in:

SavedTableHash = "2/6ijbfpfKhSdhJa3iiSuw=="

I'll edit the question with this information :)
Is there a way to ensure there is at least one "." in the path ?

Comment: Right, so: [please update your post](/help/how-to-ask) because that should not be a comment asking me for more help, that should be part of your post, asking _anyone_ for help =). Structure it as "in this code, the following criteria define what is and what isn't a path: [...], so these patterns should work: [...], and these patterns should not work: [...], and this is what I already tried, but it's not working for the following patterns: [...]".

Answer (score 0):

You could update your pattern to:

```
"[^"\/]*\/[^"]*\.[\w:.]+"
```

The pattern matches:

- `"` Match the opening `"`
- `[^"\/]*` Match 0+ times any char except `"` or `/`
- `\/` Match `/` (If the delimiter is other than `/` you don't have to escape the forward slash)
- `[^"]*\.` Match any char except `"`, then backtrack to the first dot from the end of the match
- `[\w:.]+` Match 1+ times either a word character or `:` or `.`
- `"` Match the closing `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GJOX7a/1)

Note that `[\w:.]+` might also only match dots after the last dot, and for a match only you don't need the surrounding capture group `(...)`

If the filename can contain word characters and `:` but not end on a dot:

```
"[^"\/]*\/[^"]*\.[\w:]+(?:\.[\w:]+)*"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/itqp3d/1)